# Backbone, Marionette, Jasmine: How to test jQuery deferred event

Tags: backbone.js, jasmine, marionette, jquery-deferred

I'm very new to Jasmine and Marionette and looking for some help on how to test and even just the proper way to think about testing my application. Any pointers are welcome.

I have a Marionette Controller that I use to fetch my model, instantiate my views and render them. I use a method found at the bottom of this page so that the model is fetched before the view is rendered: https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/upgradeGuide.md#marionetteasync-is-no-longer-supported.

My controller method to fetch the model and display the view looks like so:

```
showCaseById: function(id){
  App.models.Case = new caseModel({ id: id });

  var promise = App.models.Case.fetch();
  $.when(promise).then(_.bind(this.showContentView, this));
},
```

As you can see, it calls the showContentView after the model is fetched. That method is here:

```
showContentView: function(model){
  App.views.Body = new bodyView({
    model: App.models.Case
  });

  App.views.Body.on('case:update', this.submitCase, this);

  // this.layout is defined in the controller's initialize function
  this.layout.content.show(App.views.Body);
},
```

What is the proper way to test this functionality? I'd like to test the calling of the showContentView function after the completion of the promise. How should I break up the specs for this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First, spy on your showContentView method and assert it has been called:

```
it('showCaseById', function (done) {
    var controller = new Controller();
    spyOn(controller, 'showContentView');

    controller.showCaseById('foo');
    expect(controller.showContentView).toHaveBeenCalledWith(jasmine.any(caseModel));
});
```

Secondly, I would recommend you stub out the call to fetch() so you don't hit the network, but it's starting to get a bit hairy now:

```
function caseModel() {
    this.fetch = function () {
        // return a promise here that resolves to a known value, e.g. 'blah'
    };
}
```

Now, you can have a slightly stronger assertion, but this is a bit shonky because you're fiddling around with internals of your dependencies:

```
expect(controller.showContentView).toHaveBeenCalledWith('blah');
```

By overriding caseModel, when your controller method goes to create one, it gets your new version instead of the old one, and you can control the implementation of the new one just for this test.

There are ways to make this code more testable, but as it seems you're just starting out with testing I won't go into it all. You'll certainly find out those things for yourself as you do more testing.

Answer (score 0):

First, it's important to understand that `_.bind(fn, context)` doesn't actually call fn. Instead, it returns a function that when called will call `fn()`. The `context` defines the object that fn will use internally as `this`.

It's not necessary but you could write `showCaseById` as :

```
showCaseById: function(id){
  App.models.Case = new caseModel({ id: id });

  var promise = App.models.Case.fetch();
  var fn = _.bind(this.showContentView, this);
  $.when(promise).then(fn);
},
```

As I say, that is unnecessary but now you understand that `_.bind()` returns a function and that `$.when(promise).then(...)` accepts a function as its (first) argument.

To answer the actual question, you can confirm that the `App.models.Case.fetch()` promise has been fulfilled by adding a further `$.when(promise).then(...)` statement, with a test function of your own choosing.

```
showCaseById: function(id){
  App.models.Case = new caseModel({ id: id });

  var promise = App.models.Case.fetch();
  $.when(promise).then(_.bind(this.showContentView, this));

  // start: test
  $.when(promise).then(function() {
    console.log("caseModel " + id + " is ready");//or alert() if preferred
  });
  // fin: test
},
```

The second `$.when(promise).then(...)` will not interfere with the first; rather, the two will execute sequentially. The `console.log()` satatement will provide reliable confirmation that the `this.showContentView` has been called successfully and that initial rendering should have happened.

If nothing is rendered at this point or subsequently, then you must suspect that `this.showContentView` needs to be debugged.